# Search for users through an associated table via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building an app in Rails 2.3.18 and I'm trying to find all users who have specific attributes on their profiles. This is found for an individual user by `user.profile`. User profiles have columns on them like `first_name`, `last_name`, `birthday`, etc.

I'm trying to devise an ActiveRecord query to find all of the users who all have a certain first name, for example.

Something like:

`User.find(:where => {:first_name => "Tom"})`

How should I format this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 2.3, you want:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => 'profiles.first_name = "Tom"', :joins => :profile)
```

If you want to eager load the profiles, you can use `:include` instead of `:joins` like so:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => 'profiles.first_name = "Tom"', :include => :profile)
```

Rails 2.3 rolls pretty much everything into `find`, so [check out the docs for `find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) to see all the available options.

Obviously, if you are interpolating user input into the name condition, be sure to sanitize it.